# Want show $\sup_n |T_n(x)|=\infty$ for some $x\in \ell_p(\mathbb N)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $p\in (1,\infty)$. For each $n\geq 1$, let $T_n:\ell_p(\mathbb N)\to \mathbb C$ be the continuous linear functional given by $T_n(x)=\sum_{i=n}^{2n}x_i$, where $x=(x_k)_{k\geq 1}\in \ell_p(\mathbb N)$.

The claims to be proven are:

i) $\sup_n |T_n(x)|<\infty$ for all $x\in \ell_1(\mathbb N)\subset \ell_p(\mathbb N)$,

ii) there exists $x\in \ell_p(\mathbb N)$ such that $\sup_n |T_n(x)|=\infty$.

To answer i), we have from the [earlier problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2552962/determine-left-t-n-right-depending-on-n-and-p), that $||T_n||=1$. Then given $x\in \ell_1(\mathbb N)$, one has $\sup_n |T_n(x)|\leq ||x||_1<\infty$. I hope that the reason is correct.

Now, to prove ii), I do not know how. My thought says, if only it is correct, since $(\ell_p(\mathbb N))^*$ is the dual space of $\ell_p(\mathbb N)$, we may find some $i$-th coordinate functional in order to reach the conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p\in (1, \infty)$ and let $q = p/(p-1)$ be its conjugate exponent.
Let us define, for every $n$,
$$
y^{(n)} = (y^{(n)}_k)_{k\geq 1},
\qquad
y^{(n)}_k :=
\begin{cases}
1, &\text{if}\ n\leq k \leq 2n,\\
0, &\text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$
so that $T_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k y^{(n)}_k$.
By the Riesz representation theorem, we have that
$$
\|T_n\|_* = \|y^{(n)}\|_q = (n+1)^{1/q}, 
$$
so that
$$
\sup_n \|T_n\|_* = +\infty.
$$
By the Banach-Steinhaus theorem we can conclude that there exists a dense set
$D \subset \ell^p$ such that
$$
\sup_n |T_n(x)| = +\infty
\qquad \forall x\in D.
$$

Comment: I have a question, why is $\sup_n \|T_n\|_* = +\infty$, when $\{(n+1)^{1/q}:n\geq 1\}$ has no upper bound, which means that it has no supremum. To make it more general, if one set is non-empty and has no upper bound, would the supremum of it be infinity?

Comment: By definition, it is customary to set $\sup A = +\infty$ when a set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is not bounded from above.

Comment: I suppose that your answer is made for a general case. Some parts of your answer (both theorems) is out of my knowledge, but I really appreciate your help! I tried an example, similar to your first edit, namely the sequence $((\ln k)/k)_k$, and it worked.

Comment: Nice example. And yes, I have modified my first answer because 1) I have misread the question and 2) I have thought that the exercise has been assigned as an application of the Uniform Boundedness Principle.